# Including saved user data in django email

Tags: python, django, email, django-models

I've created a script that allows me to send each user an email. I'm trying to include a list of terms that is saved to each specific user as text output in the email. I've managed to get the title of all of the objects, but I really want to get the entries in the text fields named "saved_searches" and only for that specific user.

Here's the relevant model:

```
class Terms(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    saved_searches = models.TextField()
```

And here's the script that I'm working on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from app.models import Terms
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.db import connection

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    help = 'Sends emails'

    def handle_noargs(self,**options):
        try:
            self.send_email_alerts()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        finally:
            connection.close()

    def send_email_alerts(self):
        for user in User.objects.all():
            subject = 'Alerts'
            from_email="Support <support@email.com>"
            terms = Terms.objects.all()
            text = 'Hi %s, here are your alerts: %s.' % (user.username, terms)

            self.stdout.write("logging here")
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, text, from_email, [user.email])
            msg.send()

        self.stdout.write("sending complete")
```

Comment: Are you trying to sent the terms that belong to the especific user or all the terms in the database to every user?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: terms = Terms.objects.all().filter(user=user).values(saved_searches)

Comment: I'm trying to send the terms that belong to that specific user.

Comment: I was thinking something like that, but I get "saved_searches" is undefined when I use this.

Comment: I assumed that saved_searches is a field in your model, use "users_terms" or whatever fields you have defined in your Terms model

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited the post to reflect "saved_searches." I have saved_searches defined in my Terms model, but I'm getting that it is not globally defined.

Comment: sorry, you need to put the quotes in there, my first comment should have been: terms = Terms.objects.all().filter(user=user).values('saved_searches')

Comment: Then you should use terms= Terms.objects.get(user=user) or Terms.objects.filter(user=user) and you should add an try: except: in case the user dosent have any terms yet

Comment: I'd probably use a `values_list('saved_searches', flat=True)` query here - that'll give you an iterable containing just the text of the searches, which is a little bit easier to add into the text of the message. But no big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not filter the terms by the current user of the loop.
Additionally if you only need the `saved_searches` use the values_list method with the option flat=True.

```
terms = user.terms_set.values_list('saved_searches', flat=True)
```

or

```
terms = Terms.object.filter(user=user).values_list('saved_searches', flat=True)
```

For a propper formating you should join the terms before adding to the string template:

```
text = 'Hi %s, here are your alerts: %s.' % (user.username, ', '.join(terms))
```